# Get the schema of an Oracle database with python

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I want to list and describe the tables present in an Oracle database.

To do this by connecting to the database with a client such as SQL Plus, a working approach is:

1. List the tables:

   `select tablespace_name, table_name from all_tables;`
2. Get columns and data types for each table:

   `describe [table_name];`

However when using cx_Oracle through python, `cur.execute('describe [table_name]')` results in an 'invalid sql' error.

How can we use `describe` with cx_Oracle in python?

Comment: DESCRIBE is a SQL*Plus "client side" command.  SQL*Plus doesn't send it to the database. It is not a SQL statement so the database doesn't understand it.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you can't.

From cx_Oracle instead of `describe` use:

`cur.execute('select column_name, data_type from all_tab_columns where table_name = [table_name]')`

(From Richard Moore here http://cx-oracle-users.narkive.com/suaWH9nn/cx-oracle4-3-1-describe-table-query-is-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

As noted by others there is no ability to describe directly. I created a set of libraries and tools that let you do this, however. You can see them here: https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_OracleTools.